# How do I find files older than 14 days?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, unix-timestamp

I have made a small script where I am trying to find files older than 14 days but it is printing whole path with file name I just need filename .my script is below .

```
    #! /bin/bash
    . /cdunix/appl/adm/harshleen/config.cfg
    
    echo "this is first line"
    find $v -mtime +14 -ls >file.tmp
    mailx -s  "files older than 14 days " hk185109@ncr.com < file.tmp
    rm file.tmp
    echo "this is second line

"
output is 

    4461738  4 -rwxrwxrwx   1 cdadm  other   84 Jul 19 07:14 /cdunix/appl/adm/harshleen/script2.sh

I need my output to be 

    4461738  4 -rwxrwxrwx   1 cdadm  other  84 Jul 19 07:14 script2.sh

can you please help ?
```

Comment: Use the `-printf` option to `find`. See the man page for details.

Comment: There seems to be no need for the tmpfile. You could use `find ... | mailx ...`

Comment: You could probably get what you want with `find ... | sed 's@/.*/@@' | mailx ...`.

Comment: I am trying to fetch full details of file as well with filename excluding path but this is not giving me that result . It just give filename as an output

Answer (score 0):

You can use the basename command along with xargs (and remove your -ls argument).

```
find $v -mtime +14 | xargs basename > file.tmp
```

Comment: it gives error ... 
basename: extra operand ‘/cdunix/appl/adm/harshleen/script2.sh’
Try 'basename --help' for more information.
Null message body; hope that's ok

Comment: then you may want to add the -a argument in Ubuntu: find $v -mtime +14 | xargs basename -a > file.tmp

Comment: yes but it's giving output with just filename like script2.sh
scriptconfig.cfg
VariableScript.sh but I need output as 4461738  4 -rwxrwxrwx   1 cdadm  other  84 Jul 19 07:14 script2.sh